# How to handle windows authentication popup cancel button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I am using ASP.NET and C# with windows authentication and logout option. On logout i am redirecting to logout.aspx. There login button is provided for relogin.

While clicks on relogin i am doing this.

```
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.StatusCode = 401;
        Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
        Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
        Response.End();
```

It is working fine with a valid credentials. But if they click on cancel it is not calling the page load of logout.aspx but it displays the blankpage. If i click refresh it is logging into application with out asking any credentials.

During logout i am doing this.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "Service Job Card - Logout";
        if (!IsPostBack )
        {
            //Session.Abandon();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Session[SessionNames.userLoggedOut] = true;
        }
        else if (IsPostBack && Session[SessionNames.userLoginTry] == null)
        {
            Session[SessionNames.userLoginTry] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Session[SessionNames.userLoggedOut] = false;
            Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Login.aspx", true);
        }
    }
```

So in all page i am checking this session, if it is false he will be logged in.

Can someone tell me why the empty page is displayed during cancel?

Comment: It's an unusual requirement to be able to log out of a site if you're using windows authentication - since, as you've observed, just refreshing the page (or closing and re-opening the browser) will usually re-authenticate with the site automatically.

Comment: Thanks..I understood what you are telling. But based on my req i need to provide logout with windows authentication.It is working fine except when he click on cancel.if he is not clicked on cancel and try to access the page it wont allow because as you see i am using session for login check.So if i am able to track cancel button then there wont be a problem..Is it possible?

Comment: No, the cancel happens in the context of the browser, so there's nothing you can do on the server side. And, as a result of the cancel, you end up with no page loaded - so you've not got any code running on the browser side either. (Unless you want to write a browser add-in just to satisfy this requirement, and even then, I'm not sure you can get access to any suitable hooks)

Comment: Yeah..Thanks..But for info..how pressing on ok button is calling the pageload?

Answer (score 0):

When you click Relogin button, you are sending 401 status code and ending the response abruptly (`Response.End`) - the 401 status probably causes browser to ask for credentials prompt again (although associated windows ticket might have been perfectly valid).

Canceling the prompt means browser will probably stop right there and that means showing the response from previous request which was blank (because you had used `Response.End` without writing any response text).

The refresh would probably cause the post-back replay - and as per your `page_load` code, it would fall into the last else condition, setting your flag and redirecting to login.aspx. Because, the original windows auth ticket was anyway valid, browser might have used the same for subsequent requests.

You can easily validate this by using the tool such as firebug/fiddler and see what is going on.

I am afraid that there is probably no solution for your problem other than targeting different behavior. For example, on Relogin click, you can straight-away take the user to login.aspx instead of sending 401.